"AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled" despite having correct versions of everything
I am trying to run a model using cuda on linux terminal with conda virtual environment. The model uses device_map = "auto" for device assignment like the following:
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, device_map="auto")
The problem arises when the code gets to model.generate(...).to(cuda). Forgive me for not providing the full code, but I can promise no other part meddles with cuda or device at all.
Here are the things that I have checked:
nvdia-smi command shows that driver supports up to CUDA 12.0.
nvcc --version command shows I currently have CUDA 11.8.
I downloaded the corresponding packages from the command I got from https://pytorch.org/ in accordance to the system.
Yet when I run the code, it keeps emitting AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled .
torch.cuda.is_available() returns false as well.
I have tried a lot of other solutions, downloaded what everyone told to download, uninstalled packages and reinstalled them to no avail. Any suggestions on what I might have missed would be appreciated.
EDIT: Solved. Made a whole new conda environment and downloaded pytorch with python3 -m pip install pytorch instead of conda install or just pip install. Now the torch.__version__command shows '2.3.1+cu121' instead of just 2.3.1.

“Torch not compiled with CUDA” is pretty self-explanatory. The version of PyTorch you have installed has no built-in GPU support. Nothing you change with CUDA versions or drivers will have any effect. You must install a GPU enabled Pytorch build

Which exact command did you use to install pytorch? This is key as it is where your mistake lies.

@Dr.Snoopy The command pytorch.rog gave me is conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia.

@talonmies Oh so the version i downloaded from the official site does not incorporate gpu? Do you mind telling me where I can look up such info? I googled something along “conda install pytorch with gpu” and most just says to do what I did.

I would completely remove conda and install pytorch using pip, its right there in the official instructions and I can confirm it works with GPU support.

@aureum: I have no idea what you did or did not download and install. But the evidence you posted in your question clearly shows that the you have at least one non-GPU enabled Pytorch build installed and that is apparently what you are running. That may not be what you have downloaded and installed most recently. Only you know what you did

Solved it. I did try to take the pip approach instead of conda like you said. Made a whole new conda environment, and downloaded pytorch with 'python3 -m pip install pytorch'. For some reason it failed with just pip install pytorch. Used CUDA V10.1.243, pytorch '2.3.1+cu121'. Lesson of the day, don't use conda install torch. Thanks @Dr.Snoopy very much

@talonmies Yeah the problem indeed was I was using a non-GPU enabled pytorch, I did realize it but i couldn't figure out what I had to do to get a GPU one. pip worked the magic for me
